# im trying to use winsound to play wav file ONCE

Tags: python, winsound

heres my code

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('filename.wav',winsound.SND_LOOP)
```

i want to play it ONCE not in a loop.
i tried removing

```
SND_LOOP
```

but it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the `winsound.SND_LOOP` flag. Use `0` or `winsound.SND_ASYNC` flag instead.

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('filename.wav',0)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html)

Answer (score 0):

i don't have windows os to test it but according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_FILENAME) try this :

```py
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('filename.wav',winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```